# Only show the h3 if there is data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a database to present address information, however at the top I use the field CompanyName within the h3, the problem is that if there is no data, everything disappears other than the "Contact Address" how can I get this to not appear if there is no data present?

```
<h3><?php echo $directorydata->CompanyName; ?> Contact Address</h3>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->Add1; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->Add2; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->Add3; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->Town; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->County; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $directorydata->Postcode; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<?php
if(isset($directorydata->CompanyName) && trim($directorydata->CompanyName) != '') {
?>

<h3><?php echo $directorydata->CompanyName; ?> Contact Address</h3>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare it first to check data whether is it empty

```
<?php
if(!empty(trim($directorydata->CompanyName)) 
{
?>
<h3><?php echo $directorydata->CompanyName; ?> Contact Address</h3>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Again, I am not sure why but it doesnt change anything

Comment: There's no sense of using `$directorydata->CompanyName!=""` over here as you have already used `!empty($directorydata->CompanyName)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `!empty` function like as

```
<?php echo (!empty($directorydata->CompanyName)) ? "<h3> $directorydata->CompanyName Contact Address</h3> : ""; ?>
```

Here `!empty($directorydata->CompanyName)` will check that `$directorydata->CompanyName` `isset` and `not empty`

Comment: Nope this won't @RohitKumar

Comment: @OP did you checked my answer

Comment: You have modified your code , i stand on my point for your previous one

Comment: Yes its my mistake I misunderstood the question

Answer (score -1):

I think you have do iT with javascript